# How to create RewriteRule for Full path negative pattern without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got probably a little problem, which is the redirect from A to B without changing URL (still A) and send A as GET variable. And the second thing is to check if A doesn't start like /news.....

For example:
User access url: `www.custom.com/news` and rewrite does nothing here but if user access url: `www.custom.com/something/abc` it will redirect it to `www.custom.com/router.php?path=/something/abc` and visible URL for user will be still `www.custom.com/something/abc`

Now, I've got rule like this one:

```
RewriteRule !^(/news.*)$ /router.php?path=$1 [NS,R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't do the job and it creates and error for infinity loop(ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Could you give me at least some advice how to resolve my problem?

Edit.

I've changed rule a bit and add a RewriteCond but there's still infinity loop. What's wrong here?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/router\.php.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /router.php?path=$1 [NS,R=301,L]
```

Edit2.

Above code now works(I've removed escape character from condition rule), but redrect still changes URL to `www.sample.com/router.php=something/abc`

**EDIT 3:**

I was wondering why my route was displaying a little bit odd, and I found the solution.

First this is that redirect was in infinity loop so that's why I've got `www.sample.com/router.php?path=something/abc` rather than `www.sample.com/something/abc`(it looped twice and saved router.php as last URI).

Second thing is that I had L-flag where I should use it... And I've add NC-flag for sure that everything will redirect.

That's my code if it could help someone:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/router.php.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /router.php?path=$1 [NC]
```

Thanks to CBroe for help!

**EDIT 4:**

I thought that everything's fine, but now I found that when I am typing in a URL: `www.sample.com/abc` and press Enter it rewrite to the router.php and does not change URL so it is still `www.sample.com/abc`.

But when I am using links with href like: `www.sample.com/abc` it rewrite to router.php but the URL is changed too! After clicking link it's changing URL to: `www.sample.com/abc?path=abc` where I want to still have `www.sample.com/abc`

I was searching a lot and everywhere rewrite didn't make changes like mine code.
Does anyone have idea how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of trying to use a negating pattern in the RewriteRule, it’d probably be easier if you just preceded it with a `RewriteCond` that excludes any request starting with `/news` – and then just rewrite “everything” in the RewriteRule. (Might still need an exclusion of `router.php` though to avoid the endless redirect.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was creating this weird issue.

It was a slash at the end. So if url was ending without "/" at the end it was automatically adding "/" and then GET path variable.

So I did a Rule for redirecting without slash url to url with slash.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L]
```